# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on array

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, php5

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\Practicas\Blog\functions.php:27 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\Practicas\Blog\index.php(13): obtener_post('2', Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Curso\Practicas\Blog\functions.php on line 27

```
<?php 

    function conexion($bd_config){
    try {
        new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.$bd_config['basedatos'],$bd_config['usuarios'],$bd_config['pass']);
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
    return false;
    }

}

function LimpiarDatos($datos){
    $datos = trim($datos);
    $datos = stripcslashes($datos);
    $datos = htmlspecialchars($datos);
    return $datos; 
}

function pagina_actual(){
    return isset($_GET['p']) ?  (int)$_GET['p'] : 1;
}

function obtener_post($post_por_pagina, $conexion){

    $inicio = (pagina_actual() >1) ? pagina_actual() * $post_por_pagina - $post_por_pagina : 0;

    $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM CONTENIDO LIMIT {$inicio}, {$post_por_pagina}");//aqui es la linea del error

    $sentencia->execute();

    return $sentencia->fetchAll();
}



 ?>
```

Llego a pensar que el error puede provenir de aquí, ya que aquí genero los array pero, ya he mirado y no encuentro nada mal.

```
<?php 

define('RUTA','http://localhost/curso/Practicas/Blog/');


$bd_config = array('basededatos' => 'Blog',
                    'usuarios'=> 'root',
                    'pass' =>''
);

$blog_config = array(
    'post_por_pagina'=>'2',
    'carpeta_imagenes' =>'imagenes/'
);

$blog_admin=array(
    'usuario'=> 'Nicolas',
    'password'=> '456'  
);


?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que recibes es porque $conexion no es un objeto PDO, por tanto la funcion "prepare" no existe (de hecho dice que es un arreglo).

A su vez, todo se origina ya que la funcion "conexion" debería almacenar o retornar el objeto de conexión, pero actualmente solo se conecta cuando en rigor debe almacenarse para que esté disponible a lo largo de la ejecución del script.

```
<?php
$conexion = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña);
return $conexion;
?>
```

o también (no recomendado)

```
<?php
$GLOBALS['conexion'] = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=prueba', $usuario, $contraseña);
return true;
?>
```

De todas maneras falta contexto ya que no sé donde ni como estás utilizando la función "obtener_post" ni como estás pasando el objeto de conexión, pero al menos tendrás luces de qué puede estar saliendo mal.

https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php

https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.connections.php

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! y si ya corregí el error principal de no haber especificado $conexion como PDO no se como no vi eso antes pero aun así me sigue saliendo el mismo error de la función obtener_post especificamente en : ` $sentencia = $conexion->prepare("SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM CONTENIDO LIMIT {$inicio}, {$post_por_pagina}");//aqui es la linea del error`    y el error es el mismo del titulo del post

Comment: y necesito esa funcion ya que estoy almacenandola en una variable en el index y por causa de ese error no he podido

Comment: ya lo solucione,aun asi gracias :D !